# How do we enable all features for Win2k12 machine where IIS is already installed using cmd

Tags: iis, powershell, cmd, windows-server-2012, iis-8

For a Win2K8 machine we install IIS and enable all features using the command

```
ServerManagerCmd.exe -install Web-Server -allSubFeatures -resultPath C:\Admin\WebServer.xml -restart
```

How do we enable all features for Win2k12 machine where IIS is already installed using cmd ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use this:

`Get-WindowsFeature | ? {$_.Name -match "^Web-"} | Install-WindowsFeature`

> Doesn't work on Powershell 2.0

Comment: found out Dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:Hearts from cmd. But still i want to apply multiple features. Looking for options currently

Comment: If you wanted to run it from cmd.exe, you'd have to type the word powershell before the above command: `powershell Get-WindowsFeature | ? {$_.Name -match "^Web-"} | Install-WindowsFeature`

Comment: How does this answer the question, it does not test `where IIS is already installed ?` To me it looks like this would install all features on all machines regardless of whether IIS was present and that might not be the OP's intent (or am I missing something)

Comment: I think he is saying that IIS has already been installed on the machine using CMD, and he's wondering how to add all the features afterwards. I assume the command he uses initially doesn't let him add more once it's been installed.

Comment: Yes correct IIS has already been installed and the only missing piece is that some of the features are not enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

What is installed:

```
Get-WindowsFeature -Name Web* | where {$_.Installed -eq $True}
```

What is not installed:

```
Get-WindowsFeature -Name Web* | where {$_.Installed -eq $False}
```

Install what's not installed:

```
Get-WindowsFeature -Name Web* | where {$_.Installed -eq $False} | Install-WindowsFeature
```

I used the -WhatIf Common Parameter on the last one and got a warning about needing an install source. You may need to research the -Source parameter of Install-WindowsFeature cmdlet.